# Enabling Views module causing cron to fail

Tags: views, 7, cron, users

Quite simply, I enable the super common "Views" module, and on Save nothing but a white page happens. 
On a refresh (Where I agree to the form resubmission) the modules page comes back just fine.

Then I click the "Run cron" link, and that is also blank, and never shows anything else or redirects.

Visiting cron.php by itself, also blank.

I've seen some solutions, such as increasing php's memory_limit and mysql's max_allowed_packet, but neither have done anything.

Everything runs optimally again the moment I disable Views.

**Some info**:

Web server: nginx/1.4.6
PHP: 5.5.9
PHP memory limit: 256M
Drupal: 7.35

I've never had this problem before, especially with Views

Comment: Check your server error log, there may be more debug info there.

Comment: @DavidThomas   
  
2015/03/30 19:17:50 [error] 10141#0: *13601 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class view in /var/www/[redacted]/sites/all/modules/views/includes/view.inc on line 19" while reading response header from upstream, client: 208.91.114.4, server: [redacted], request: "GET /admin/structure/block HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "[redacted]", referrer: "[redacted]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like either:

1. You have two copies of the Views module enabled somehow.
2. You have a problem with your server configuration in relation to op-code caching.

Check your "system" table in the database with:

```
SELECT name, filename, status FROM system WHERE name = 'views';
```

Check the results are as expected for your install.

For the op-code cache issue, check this thread:

> Cannot redeclare class view, updating to PHP5.5

https://www.drupal.org/node/2066561

It may be a problem with using multiple op-code caching methods, or xcache conf issue.

Comment: Hi thank you! 

The query only returned the one result `views | sites/all/modules/views/views.module | 1`

but yeah even clearing out the views module and jumping around a bunch of versions, they all produce the same result :|

Comment: The cache config did it

`vi /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` and uncommenting `opcache.enable=0` worked (after restarting php5-fpm of course)